# I need to be able to run pycharm + modules off of a USB

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, usb-drive

I need to run Pycharm using pygame/numpy on multiple computers from a USB drive.

I have to submit a "create" project, which I'm doing a a game using pygame. To make this game, I use Pycharm, a python IDE, along with the modules pygame and numpy. When I program at home, I have no issues. I have all the files, pycharm, winpython, and all the files I need on my USB, and it uses the interpeter that is on my USB.

When I get to school, however is when the problems occur. My first issue is that Pycharm won't let me run my programs. I get "Interpreter is not found" or something like that, and I haven't been able to solve this issue. What I've tried is to rename the path to the python interpreter Z:/path (what the usb is at home) to D:/path.

What I've tried:

I have also tried making a persistent USB, so that I could install ubuntu, then pycharm,python,pyagme, and numpy. I however failed, and every time O fixed on error with the USB I would get another. I managed to put Ubuntu on the USB and get it to load, but I haven't been able to get the data to save after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a correct python interpreter with the necessary modules on your USB key it will be quite easy.
Open pycharm. Go to Files/Settings/Project Interpreter. Select the correct python.exe in the left menu.

Now leave the settings. Click on Add Configuration on the top right of the main page. Select python, then the interpreter you just added and in Script Path select the script you want to run.
Just click play next to Add Configuration and you can run your programs without installing anything.